# Using .htaccess to route to two different applications in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have two codeigniter applications similar to this [example](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html). I've created two `index.php` files like the example says(the second one is named oglasnik.php). I want to call applications without the name of the file that calls the desired application.

I take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531504/847773) as an example for me. So the my .htaccess file right now is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /PublishWall/
    DirectoryIndex indexl.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ indexl.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ indexl.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond $1 !^(indexl\.php|oglasnik\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^oglasnik$ oglasnik.php [L]

 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 </IfModule> 
php_value date.timezone "Europe/Ljubljana"
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

When I route to oglasnik I get 404 Page Not Found, shouldnt this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^oglasnik$ oglasnik.php [L]
```

rewrite it to oglasnik.php. When I go to oglasnik.php it works fine.

Also I am curios to find out how this routing actualy works. Does the rewritten url visit the .htacces file again, something I see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612329/847773).

The rewrite log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/oglasnik -> oglasnik
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'oglasnik'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] RewriteCond: input='/PublishWall/oglasnik' pattern='^system.*' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/oglasnik -> oglasnik
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'oglasnik'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] RewriteCond: input='oglasnik' pattern='!^(indexl\.php|oglasnik\.php|images|robots\.txt)' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] RewriteCond: input='/PublishWall/oglasnik' pattern='^application.*' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/oglasnik -> oglasnik
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] applying pattern '^(oglasnik)$' to uri 'oglasnik'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (2) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] rewrite 'oglasnik' -> 'oglasnik.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] add per-dir prefix: oglasnik.php -> C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/oglasnik.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (2) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] trying to replace prefix C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/ with /PublishWall/
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (4) add subst prefix: oglasnik.php -> /PublishWall/oglasnik.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#15b10d8/initial] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] internal redirect with /PublishWall/oglasnik.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/oglasnik.php -> oglasnik.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'oglasnik.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] RewriteCond: input='/PublishWall/oglasnik.php' pattern='^system.*' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/oglasnik.php -> oglasnik.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'oglasnik.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] RewriteCond: input='oglasnik.php' pattern='!^(indexl\.php|oglasnik\.php|images|robots\.txt)' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/oglasnik.php -> oglasnik.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] applying pattern '^(oglasnik)$' to uri 'oglasnik.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2013:23:35:36 +0100] [localhost/sid#991d38][rid#151b500/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/] pass through C:/wamp/www/PublishWall/oglasnik.php
```

Comment: In your oglasnik rule, the RewriteCond is checking against $1, the first character sequence captured in the RewriteRule -- but you don't capture anything there, so it's never true, hence the 404 error. Wrapping oglasnik in parantheses may give better results. As for the flow of mod_rewrite: check out the incredibly enlightening [flowchart](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/images/rewrite_process_uri.png) and the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset). That flowchart is really, really a must-see.

Comment: Thanks for the link of the flowchart. Though the parenthesses dont help. In the edit of the post I will add the rewrite log, of this rewriting.

Comment: I have found out that I actually reach the codeigniter application that I want but it goes to 404_override

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(indexl\.php|oglasnik\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^oglasnik.*$ oglasnik.php?/$1 [L]
```