# Codeigniter multiple application 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to configure codeigniter with multiple application which will share common CI resources,

I did renamed application to applications and created two applications like below,

```
www\app1\application\controller...models...view
www\app2\application\controller...models...view
www\system\
```

and id1.php and id2.php are duplicate of index.php,

then i changed application path in app1.php and app2.php as below,

in app1.php -- `$application_folder =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'app1/application';`

in app2.php -- `$application_folder =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'app2/application';`

and created .htaccess file as below,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app1/id1.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Problem...

When i load `http://localhost/app1/welcome`, it work fine,
but when i load `http://localhost/app2/welcome` it throw `404 page not found`. I assume this is because htacess file, how to add two id1.php and id2.php in htacess file?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know if what you are trying is possible, but when you access the url `http://localhost/app1/welcome` ci would look for a controller named `App1.php` and a method `welcome` in that controller. which clearly is not available.

Comment: @SayantanDas, but it is mentioned same in user guide, http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html

Comment: Okay i have gone through the doc. Try changing the url to `http://localhost/app1.php/welcome`

Comment: Are you really wanting to share the application folder?  Or are you more looking to share the main CI system files?

Comment: @cfnerd, i want to share only CI system files

Comment: @SayantanDas, yes i could able to use that url, but now i had modified some structure, can you tell me how to add two index,php files in htaccess to remove index.php?

Comment: I'm not good with htaccess, but i found these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531504/codeigniter-multi-application-htaccess-problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307685/codeigniter-multi-application-htaccess-issue
you can have a look at them